# splitting a string into only two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string that reads "20 years in Germany" that need to be be split into two columns using SQL. One column containing the number 20 and the second column containing the string 'years in Germany'.

I have used the string_split function using a space on the as the splitting character. However, the issue is that I am ending up getting two many values from the split.

```
declare @message varchar(100) = '20 years in Germany';
select
(
select top 1 [value] from string_split([value], ' ') order by value asc -- get the number 20 in the string
)


My desired result is two columns 

------------- ----------------
20            years in Germany
```

Comment: Show us some more sample data, of different kinds, and also the expected result.

Comment: `string_split` returns rows, not columns. If you want what's before the first space as one part and what's after it on the other part, use a combination of `left`, `right`, `len`  and `charindex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `PATINDEX`

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX) = '20 years in Germany' 

SELECT LEFT(@str, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @str )) AS Number,
       LTRIM(RIGHT(@str, LEN(@str) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @str ))) As word
```

output

```
Number  word
20      years in Germany
```